# Perform logical operations and add new columns of dataframe in the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Since I'm new and learning python, I want to collect specific data in dataframe corresponding to logical operation and add a label to it, however, this needs to perform in many lines of code.

For example:

```
df = df[(df['this_col'] >= 10) & (df['anth_col'] < 100)]
result_df = df.copy()
result_df['label'] = 'medium'
```

I really wonder if there's a way such that I can perform in one line of code without applying a function. If it cannot perform in one line, how come?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query` returns a copy, always.

```
result_df = df.query("this_col >= 10 and anth_col < 100").assign(label='medium')
```

Assuming your columns can pass off as valid identifier names in python, this will do.